# Mysql query showing different result in IE8 and (FF,chrome)

Tags: php, mysql, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I have developed cms in core php, I have simple search form in admin section to search database.
When I run mysql select query, its showing different result in IE8 and FF

My **query** :

```
$q = "select * from users where FirstName='Linda' and LastName='Anderson'";
```

In FF and Chrome this query shows 3 records which is correct, but in IE8 it only shows one record

Comment: That has nothing to do with PHP; let's see the HTML that gets output

Comment: share your HTML code to display the results..

Comment: can you please check your html code or else paste the code.

Comment: there might be cache problem clear cache in all browsers and check the result. if it does not work append ?time=3832948398 to check

Comment: Database not have UI issues :P